# Rtaudio in DLL makes program unresponsive

Tags: c++, vb.net, audio, dll

I would like to make a DLL in C++ that streams sound to the speakers and that I can call from a Visual Basic program. Creating the dll and calling its functions from a VB program worked. However, as soon as I declare an Rtaudio object in the DLL, it makes the Visual Basic program unresponsive (and there is no sound). If I use the exact same code in a console application project instead of in a DLL everything works fine and I hear sound. As I am inexperienced in DLL programming, I have absolutely no idea what could cause such a problem. Could you give me any hints what might be wrong?

This is part of my code. It still produces the same problem:
DLL:

```
//C and C++ libraries
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <valarray>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <Windows.h>

//BOOST thread library for multi-threading
#include <boost\thread.hpp>

//Include RtAudio
#include <RtAudio.h>

#ifdef AUDIODLL1_EXPORTS
    #define AUDIODLL1_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
    #define AUDIODLL1_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

RtAudio dac;       //If I leave this line out, everything works well

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:          
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }


    return TRUE;
}


AUDIODLL1_API int __stdcall getNumber()
{
    return 5;
}
```

This is the .def file:

```
LIBRARY AudioDll1
DESCRIPTION 'Audio DLL Test 1'

EXPORTS
    getNumber
```

And this is the VB example code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Function getNumber Lib "AudioDll1.dll" () As Integer

    Dim myNum As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Text = 10

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = 1
        myNum = getNumber()
        Label1.Text = 2
        Label1.Text = myNum
    End Sub
End Class
```

As I said, the only problem is the

```
RtAudio dac;
```

I tried declaring it locally, putting it in a thread etc. Nothing works. However, if I just create a win32 console application, include the same headers, link the same libraries, everything works well. These are the libs I'm linking to:

```
dsound.lib
rtaudiolib.lib
kernel32.lib
user32.lib
advapi32.lib
ole32.lib
```

I do not inherit from parent or project defaults.

Oh and I'm aware that even if it would work, I would not hear sound using the code above. As I said, I tried deleting portions of the code to find the problem. And RtAudio dac; is all it takes to cause it.

EDIT: I should also add, that rtaudiolib.lib is a static libary I made from the Rtaudio 4.0.12 code using

```
#define __WINDOWS_DS__ 
#define __WINDOWS_ASIO__
```

I would immensely appreciate any help.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RtAudio constructor is calling RtApiDs::getDeviceCount() which in turn was calling DirectSoundEnumerate() which is a function of dsound.dll.

I always tried to declare the RtAudio object during DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH (or in global space, which seems to cause the same problem).

Microsoft states that one should not load other libraries during DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx

> The entry-point function should perform only simple initialization or
>   termination tasks. It must not call the LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx
>   function (or a function that calls these functions), because this may
>   create dependency loops in the DLL load order. This can result in a
>   DLL being used before the system has executed its initialization code.
>   Similarly, the entry-point function must not call the FreeLibrary
>   function (or a function that calls FreeLibrary) during process
>   termination, because this can result in a DLL being used after the
>   system has executed its termination code.

So I decided not to do anything in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH and have a separate custom init() function for my DLL. This solved all issues.